# Output even or non-even elements of an array?

Tags: php

There is a task. the function accepts the parameter 'odd' or 'even' - strings and array. And it returns the number of either odd or even elements in the array, depending on the parameter. Tell me where I was wrong?

```html
function () {
$num = 'even';
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
in_array($num, $arr) {
    if($num == 'even') {
        return $arr % 2 == 0;
 } else {
    return $arr % 2 !== 0;
 }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your result. In your program, you are performing a modular operation on an entire array, which is not supported. You need to check each element of an array.

```
$result = [];
$num = 'even';
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
function _in_array($num, $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $value){
        if($num == 'even'){
            if($value % 2 == 0){
                $result[] = $value;
            }
        }else{
             if($value % 2 != 0){
                $result[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
 }
```

Comment: PHP has a built-in function called `in_array()`. I suggest renaming the function to avoid a redeclaration error.